# Use Jquery to detect a word in a string that contains a dash, and then output that word without the dash

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to look for a word in a string that has a dash, save that to a variable, and then have 2 other variables that display it with a space, and one with no space. For example:

string: Her surname is Smith-Johnson

word variable: Smith-Johnson

nospace variable: SmithJohnson

space variable: Smith Johnson

I'm able to save the entire string with or without the dash, but I'd like to just save the word that the dash is in. Here's my code that does the entire string:

```
var dashNoSpace = deviceSize.substring().replace('-', '');
var dashSpace = deviceSize.substring().replace('-', ' ');
var dashReplace = deviceSize.replace(/(((\w+-)+\w+)(?![^<]*\>))/m, dashNoSpace + ',' + dashSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JS split() function (no jQuery required) to split the string into words. This will create an array that you can then search for the dash, and do your replaces in the array element containing the dash.